# How to get a comma separation between numbers in an array?

Tags: javascript

I am having beginners trouble with comma separation from numbers extracted using regular expressions. The exercise is as follows:

Find and print all the digits from the sentence as a single array. If the sentence has no digits, print "No digits!". Try to do the check using the test()-method.

This is my result: [Screenshot of the code and result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPHaw.png)

```js
var sentence = "5om3 wr173 w0rd5 u51n9 numb3r5"

function printDigits() {
  var res = sentence.replace(/\D/g, '');
  console.log(res)
}

printDigits();
```

Comment: Your replacing `\D` with `''`, where do you think the comma's should come from?

Comment: What is your expected output and where do commas come into this?

Comment: @jarmod I might be going the wrong way for this task. But from screenshot you can see the expected output has commas between the numbers when extracted.

Comment: `sentence.replace(/\D/g, '').split('')`

Comment: It indicates you should use [`test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) so think about turning the original sentence into an array and then `test()`ing each character. `[...sentence].filter((char) => /\d/.test(char));`

Comment: Do you want integers in the array, or string representations of those integers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could [`spread`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) the final number to get an `array`, then use [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to add those comma's. (join uses `,` as the default separator

As a fallback, you can use OR `||` to set the value of `res` to a string you like

```js
var sentence = "5om3 wr173 w0rd5 u51n9 numb3r5"

function printDigits() {
    var res = [ ...sentence.replace(/\D/g, '') ].join() || "No digits!";
    console.log(res)
}

printDigits();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get comma separation by converting the string to an array and then joining seperated by commas with the join method

```js
var sentence = "5om3 wr173 w0rd5 u51n9 numb3r5"

function printDigits() {
  var res = sentence.replace(/\D/g, '');
  console.log(Array.from(res).join(','))
}

printDigits();
```

Comment: This code also works! how do I incorporate in the code: if the sentence has no digits, it prints "No digits!". Into this code? thanks

Comment: Add `OR "No digits!"` check

Answer (score 1):

If you follow the question's prompt to use [`test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) this becomes a matter of testing each character, rather than manipulating the string.

In long hand you can iterate over the string itself, here using a [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop

```js
function printDigits(str) {
  const res = [];

  for (const char of str) {
    if (/\d/.test(char)) {
      res.push(char);
    }
  }

  return res.length ? res.join(', ') : 'No digits!';
}

const sentence = '5om3 wr173 w0rd5 u51n9 numb3r5';

console.log(printDigits(sentence));
console.log(printDigits('This has no digits.'));
```

This can be shortened somewhat using [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to convert the string to an array and then the array [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method to only keep those characters that pass the `test()`.

```js
function printDigits(str) {
  const res = [...str].filter((char) => /\d/.test(char));
  return res.length ? res.join(', ') : 'No digits!';
}

const sentence = '5om3 wr173 w0rd5 u51n9 numb3r5';

console.log(printDigits(sentence));
console.log(printDigits('This has no digits.'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `replacing` characters use [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) which returns an array based on a regex pattern. You can even pass in an argument specifying if you want to return an array of strings or numbers.

```js
const sentence1 = '5om3 wr173 w0rd5 u51n9 numb3r5';
const sentence2 = 'This sentence has no digits';

function printDigits(sentence, type = 'str') {
  const match = sentence.match(/\d/g);
  if (!match) return 'No digits';
  return type === 'num' ? match.map(Number) : match;
}

console.log(printDigits(sentence1, 'num'));
console.log(printDigits(sentence1));
console.log(printDigits(sentence2));
```